# Respecting rvmrc while cd in ruby script

Tags: ruby, git, rvm, rvmrc

**Background:** I wrote a short script in MRI 1.9.2p320 for updating all my projects – http://git.io/eez8Kg . Tool which i utilize for the updating/pulling itself ([git-up](https://github.com/aanand/git-up)) is also able to automatically bundle project after it discover changed Gemfile. The problem is, that when i change directory in the Ruby script, it does not respect rvmrc/gemset of projects (each project has it's own gemset).

**Question:** How can i achieve to make `cd` in Ruby script behave same as in my terminal

**I've tried:**

- replace `Dir.chdir` with cd command in the `s
- replace `Dir.chdir` with cd command in the `s prepended with `zsh -ci`

**Code:**

```
Find.find('../..') do |f|
  if f =~ /\.git$/
    repository = f.gsub /\.git$/, ''
    Logger.new(STDOUT).info('Checking '){repository}
    Dir.chdir(repository){
      puts `git up`
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: What's the result of 
puts `pwd`

Is it what you expect? I believe jruby 1.7.0 and 1.7.1 do not work as expected, not sure about MRI.

Comment: Pwd should be in backticks

Comment: It's mri 1.9.2p320. It's changing the directories, but it does not change gemset

Comment: Yes i could, but it would be writing gemset changing again. I want to get working what is already done

Comment: Uhm,it could be dynamically done.. rvm is wrapping some stuff around the cd function and I'm pretty sure mri isn't able to access this since it's most likely bash specific. I mean you only need a handful of codeline to read the rvmrc and use the gemset out of it. It's basicly what your .rvmrc does.

Comment: I appreciate you all are trying to help. But i don't want workaround, i want to get working what is working somewhere else

Comment: Okay, let me explain it to you again: RVM is using a Wrapperfunction like this: cd () 
{ 
    builtin cd "$@";
    local result=$?;
    __rvm_project_rvmrc;
    __rvm_after_cd;
    return $result
} <-- Now my question: How did you even load RVM within your rubyscript? You know you have to initiate RVM when starting your shell by adding the PATH. And this: [ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function <---- If you use your script rvm won't load properly and you wont have those functions unless you somehow initiate them..

Comment: gulty: I don't and don't want to load rvm in the ruby script since there is already configured shell to do that. On IRC some guy proposed Open3 would solve my issue and it seems it does. I'll try it at evening more deeply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Open3.html#popen3](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3) FTW

```
zshin, zshout, zsherr = Open3.popen3('zsh') # Open new shell
zshin.puts 'cd ~/Projects/superimportant_project' # Change directory
zshin.puts 'rvm-prompt' # Verify rvmrc is respected
zshin.puts 'exit' # Exit the shell
while (line = zshout.gets)
  puts line
end
```

Exiting the shell is not mandatory, but for example `rvm-prompt` stayed hanging, without  letting nothing else happen. If you try same thing with ls, you not gonna need the exit line.

- Big thanks to yorickpeterse@Freenode#ruby-lang who put me on the Open3 rail
- Additional useful reading -> [6 Ways to Run Shell Commands in Ruby](http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html)